# Hour conversion in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data-set that has time (hours) data in it.

The time data is given as `0.1123`, `3.1565`, `0.2951` etc (all in hours).

How do I convert it into standard hours and minute format?

Comment: What do the decimal parts represent? fractions of an hour? or 2 digits of minutes followed by two digits of seconds?

Comment: Ok, I guess the 65 at the end of the second value answers the question in my comment

Answer (score 1):

### We can achieve this using two methods

#### 1.Change to Date & Time

Once the data has been imported in Tableau. Change the data type of the column to ***"Date & Time"***. Tableau data engine automatically understand the time format and change the decimal time to Actual time 
[Refer this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPPT1.png)

#### 2. Using Calculated Field "MAKETIME"

MAKETIME Requires three argument(hour, minute, second).Below code parse decimal number **"3.1545"** as
3 hrs, 9 min (0.15*60) and 16 sec (0.0045*3600)

> MAKETIME(INT([DecimalTime]),
>   int(INT(([DecimalTime]*100)%100)*.6),
>   int(INT(([DecimalTime]*10000)%100)*.36))

Answer (score 0):

`Floor([value])` = the number of  hours

`Floor([value] * 60) % 60` = the number of minutes

`Floor([value] * 3600) % 3600` = the number of seconds